# How to simplify a rational function with floating point real coefficients (GCF)

Tags: algorithms, computer-algebra

How does one compute the simplified form of a rational function where the coefficients of the polynomial are floating point numbers (real, though I expect using complex numbers would be the same).

Wikipedia says it is possible using SVD, but I'm unsure about how to represent the polynomial so as to do use this.

Comment: What do you mean by simplified form?  Do you mean, dividing by common factors?  Floating point is not suitable for this.  Floating point is for representing approximate numbers, but for computing the greatest common factor, you need exact arithmetic.  $p(x)$ might divide $q(x)$ but it won't divide $q(x)+\varepsilon$; and floating point numbers don't let you distinguish $q(x)$ from $q(x)+\varepsilon$.  Basically, your question doesn't make sense.  If you need to do this, you need to avoid using floating point.  Where does Wikipedia say it is possible?  Can you edit your question to link to it?

Comment: Sure, it's got to be approximation. Wikipedia mentions the existence of approximate methods.

Comment: I encourage you to edit your question to clarify these points.  I suggest you clarify (a) what you mean by a simplified form, (b) what kind of approximation you're talking about and what amount of approximation is acceptance and what metric for approximation error you are using, (c) add links to the relevant part of Wikipedia that you refer to.

Comment: It sounds like you understand what I'm asking perfectly well, I don't know why you're acting like it doesn't make sense.

Comment: 1. Because it's not just about me; I also care about trying to ensure this question will be useful to others as well.  Part of our mission on this site is to create an archive of high-quality questions and answers.  For that reason, we want high-quality questions that stand on their own and provide all relevant information.  Comments exist to help you identify ways to improve the question, but you shouldn't leave clarifications only in comments; people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand the question, and comments can disappear at any time.

Comment: 2. And, because at the moment I *don't* understand perfectly well what you're asking.  I can only guess what kind of approximation you consider appropriate, or what kinds of answers would be suitable.  I shouldn't have to guess; you should provide a careful definition.  How will you determine whether $q(x)$ qualifies as an approximate divisor of $p(x)$?  What are the criteria?  The question doesn't currently say, and readers shouldn't be forced to speculate.  Also, if you want others to help you, it's helpful to provide relevant context -- such as what document said that SVD is applicable.

Comment: I respect your enthusiasm for this community. I've been on other SE sites and I think I know a dead question when I see it. If I though what you were asking for were worth the time I would change it. simplified -> irreducible would go a long way, I think, but the kind of details you're asking for could only really be added by someone who wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place (I would expect that there's only a couple of widely used algorithms, making the set of criteria with a practicable and well understood solution rather small).

Comment: You *do* understand what I'm asking, you just think I should be asking something else. Which is fine.